# RegEx : Non capturing group

Tags: regex, validation, dns

I'm using the following regular expression to validate a domain.tld (with subdomains)

```
^(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]{2,17}$
```

I didn't wrote that for myself I am just using it.

I don't understand that "?:" at the beginning. 
Why did the Author use a non capturing group in that case ? The Regex still works correctly without "?:"

Comment: it works for one time , for one or more times, you must use capturing or non-capturing group followed by a `+`

Comment: I think I do understand it know.. :)